# How to call function passed (function ptr passed as argument to function)

Tags: c++, function-pointers

In the command_rq line below, which does not compile, how do I call the function in this case?  How do I need to change the function to get this to work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Command {
    bool RequestA() { cout << "RequestA\n"; return true; }
    bool RequestB() { cout << "RequestB\n"; return true; }
    bool RequestC() { cout << "RequestC\n"; return true; }
};

typedef bool (Command::*Request)();

class handler {
public:
    handler(Command* cmd) : command_(cmd) { }

    // *** How to now call specific function passed?
    void doX(Request rq) { command_->rq(); }
    void doA() { doX(&Command::RequestA); }
    void doB() { doX(&Command::RequestA); }
    void doC() { doX(&Command::RequestA); }
private:
    Command* command_;
};

int main() {
    Command* pCmd = new Command;
    handler h(pCmd);
    h.doA();
}
```

Comment: `(command_->*rq)();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper sytax is this:

```
(command_->*rq)();
```

However, your code won't compile as these lines are illegal:

```
void doA() { doX(command_->RequestA); }
void doB() { doX(command_->RequestA); }
void doC() { doX(command_->RequestA); }
```

Pointers to member functions have an implicit this parameter and you can't pass it in your calls.

You'll have to alter the function to take a pointer to a Command object so that the passed function pointer has an object it can be "called on":

```
void doX(Request rq,Command* cmd) {
    (cmd->*rq)();
}
void doA() { doX(&Command::RequestA, command_); }
void doB() { doX(&Command::RequestB, command_); }
void doC() { doX(&Command::RequestC, command_); }
```

You can also get round it by declaring the functions as static and creating a simple pointer to a bool* function.

```
class Command
{
public:
    static bool RequestA() { cout << "RequestA\n"; return true; }
    static bool RequestB() { cout << "RequestB\n"; return true; }
    static bool RequestC() { cout << "RequestC\n"; return true; }
};

typedef bool (*Request)();

class handler
{
public:
    handler(Command* cmd) : command_(cmd) { }

    // *** How to now call specific function passed?
    void doX(Request rq) {
                            (rq)();
                        }
    void doA() { doX(command_->RequestA);}
    void doB() { doX(command_->RequestB); }
    void doC() { doX(command_->RequestC); }

private:
    Command* command_;
};


int main(){

    Command* pCmd = new Command;
    handler h(pCmd);
    h.doA();
    h.doB();
    h.doC();
}
```

Comment: Your answer wasn't quite correct because handler class has a ptr member to Command object.  The (command_->*rq)(); syntax in doX works without your other stuff.

Comment: Ha you're right.  It wouldn't compile on my machine last week but now it does.  I must have changed something to break it but goodness knows what it was.

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply:

```
void doA() { command_->RequestA(); }
```